# java script image path when deploying

Tags: javascript, image, path

I use java script to solve the image source. it works fine on my personal computer in development.
It doesn't work no matter which path I give it in deployment on the server.
this is the image path I use in the script

```
var imagePath = "base/pics/";
```

this is the way I submit the image source:

```
document.getElementById("mainImg").src = imagePath + imageFiles[i];
```

what am I doing wrong?

UPDATE:
Thanks for the answers. in case you are wondering, the following paths worked for me:

```
 var imagePath1 = "base/pics/";
    var imagePath2 = "/base/pics/";
    var imagePath3 = "\\base\\pics\\";
```

Comment: what is imageFiles[i] holds?

Comment: does imageFiles[i] include extension?  What is the error?

Comment: i think, you need to provide the whole imagePath of the server.

Comment: imageFiles is an array of the file sources: for ex: var imageFiles = ['once.jpg','hello.jpg',......

Comment: Yep, there are some issues with relative pathes. I prefer to use only absolute URLs for resources like images or CSS. Without specifying of protocol, of course.